# Regex for a line containing only two capital letters

Tags: regex, power-automate-desktop

I am looking for Regex (to be used in Power Automate Desktop) for finding a line containing only two capital letters. So in below example, it should find only line 5 as the correct choice.

I tried following. It works in [regex101](https://regex101.com/) website but for some reason it doesn't work in Power Automate. Any suggestions to correct this regex?

```
\b[A-Z]{2}\b\n
```

Sample text:

```
HEllo, how are you
This IS test message
is this OK
where are you. I
AM
here.
```

Comment: Why not `^[A-Z]{2}$`? `\b` is a word boundary

Comment: What kind of regex does Power Automate use? Maybe it doesn't support word boundries. Try something simpler like `[A-Z][A-Z]\n`

Comment: Kinttl and AaronJ,  I had already tried both the options but for Power Automate doesn't find the location of "AM". It isn't clear to me why it is doing that.

Comment: @MikeM I am using Power Automate Desktop and it does support Regex. It has option to select "Is regular expression".

Comment: Okay, docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/text): "Power Automate Desktop's regular expression engine is [.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)."

Comment: Thanks Mike! I Checked the docs again and found that following works: [A-Z][A-Z]\r
I am still quite new to regex which is a really powerful tool!

Comment: Are you missing the carriage return character? I.e. use `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work `.*\n([A-Z]{2})\n.*`

Answer (score 0):

This is the regular expression that worked for me. Thanks @MikeM and others for quick answers!

```
\n([A-Z]{2})\r
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```cs
(?m)^[A-Z]{2}\r?$
```

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?m)                     set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                           matching start and end of line) (case-
                           sensitive) (with . not matching \n)
                           (matching whitespace and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]{2}                 any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \r?                      '\r' (carriage return) (optional (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
```